# Monitor the health of weblogic server through script

Tags: java, weblogic

When I start my weblogic server, there are various logs printed. The structure of logging on weblogic can be found on [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/logging/logging_services.html#wp1181596).

I'm writing a script to test, whether weblogic server started successfully. I need to filter only `<Error>` log messages, however, with one condition, that, following them is some java exception. So, particularly failure of some java bean (through thrown exceptions) is the only criteria for failure of the server.

I want to ignore all other sorts of `<Error>` logs.
Is there some tool which can help in this?

**Update:**

Example of normal `<Error>`, these types of errors should be ignored:

```
    <May 29, 2015 5:02:44 PM IST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <|E |17:02:44 |2 |VGORADE01 |CorrelationID=VGORADE01_2_1432899124676 |'HotDirectory': /hot does not exist: disabling service.>
    <May 29, 2015 5:02:44 PM IST> <Error> <APM> <BEA-000000> <|E |17:02:44 |2 |VGORADE01 |CorrelationID=VGORADE01_2_1432899124676 |'ColdDirectory': /cold does not exist: disabling service.>
    <May 29, 2015 5:02:44 PM IST> <Notice> <Stdout> <BEA-000000> <|E |17:02:44 |2 |VGORADE01 |CorrelationID=VGORADE01_2_1432899124676 |'ColdDirectory': /cold does not exist: disabling service.>
```

Example of `<Error>`, which indicate failure, notice that there is stacktrace of exceptions thrown:

```
<May 29, 2015 11:51:37 PM IDT> <Error> <APM> <BEA-000000> <|E |23:51:37 |com.amdocs.crm.uif.OrderingBackendAdapter

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amdocs.crm.uif.OrderingBackendAdapter
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at com.amdocs.uif.server.UifBackendConnector.initialize(UifBackendConnector.java:72)
        at com.amdocs.uif.server.UifServerRequestResponseMgr.initializeImpl(UifServerRequestResponseMgr.java:421)
```

Comment: please provide an example; but, if you use linux awk or grep are your best friends

Comment: @venergiac, Updated an example. sadly I work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this small script helps. It is not perfect but maybe all you need to grep WLS log files for full log file entries even they go over multiple lines:

https://github.com/freeella/grepWlsLogFile

```
$ grepWlsLogFile.pl -f /path/to/AdminServer.log -s Error -c "Exception:"
```

But you must use the log file. STDOUT is much more problematic to parse because the message might span multiple lines like in your exception and might contain unpredictable occurrences of < and >.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows server you can use find command like grep on unix

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs>

type AdminServer.log|find /i "Error"

Like this you can use windows tail utility to tail file and apply above find command to find the recent exceptions or use find multiple times to first find by date then by error like below command

type AdminServer.log|find /i "Jun 4"| find /i "Error"